# Converting WKT to ASCII art?

Tags: well-known-text, ascii

I often end up writing basic geometries in unit tests, looking much like the following:

```
a = "POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))";
b = "POLYGON ((0 0, 9 0, 9 9, 0 9, 0 0))";
```

If I'm feeling ambitious, I might add a comment like this:

```
// ----------------------
// |      A             |
// |-----------------|  |
// |                 |  |
// |                 |  |
// |        B        |  |
// |                 |  |
// |                 |  |
// ----------------------
```

Clearly the technique has some limitations.  But it can be useful, which lead me to wonder if there's a magic tool out there that would take WKT (or something easily producible, like SVG) and create an ASCII representation like the example above?

Google led me to [Geometry Commands](https://github.com/jericks/geometrycommands), through I was disappointed to see that their [asciiart command](http://jericks.github.io/geometrycommands/commands/asciiart.html) produces the following:

```
 ____    ___   _     __   __  ____   ___   _   _     __  __  ___      ___        _   ___      ___        _   ___     _   ___         ___     _   ___         ___      ___  __  __  
|  _ \  / _ \ | |    \ \ / / / ___| / _ \ | \ | |   / / / / / _ \    / _ \      / | / _ \    / _ \      / | / _ \   / | / _ \       / _ \   / | / _ \       / _ \    / _ \ \ \ \ \ 
| |_) || | | || |     \ V / | |  _ | | | ||  \| |  | | | | | | | |  | | | | _   | || | | |  | | | | _   | || | | |  | || | | | _   | | | |  | || | | | _   | | | |  | | | | | | | |
|  __/ | |_| || |___   | |  | |_| || |_| || |\  |  | | | | | |_| |  | |_| |( )  | || |_| |  | |_| |( )  | || |_| |  | || |_| |( )  | |_| |  | || |_| |( )  | |_| |  | |_| | | | | |
|_|     \___/ |_____|  |_|   \____| \___/ |_| \_|   \_\ \_\ \___/    \___/ |/   |_| \___/    \___/ |/   |_| \___/   |_| \___/ |/    \___/   |_| \___/ |/    \___/    \___/ /_/ /_/
```

Nice, but not quite what I was going for.  Anyone aware of another tool out there?

Comment: So what *are* you going for?

Comment: Something like my example.

Comment: You said you were disappointed with what was produced and that it's not quite what you were going for.

Comment: See the first image.

Comment: I'm thinking this is borderline if not completely off-topic for GIS SE

Comment: Wondering if there could be a route by using SVG as an interim format.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that your question is relevant to GIS?

Comment: @PolyGeo Because it deals with processing WKT, which is a GIS format?

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you explain why you edited the question title into something that's not grammatical English?

Comment: More concise titles work better for sharing questions via Twitter etc. There are some Meta posts here and at Meta SE that recommend "How to" not be used at the beginning of question titles on SE sites.

Comment: Certainly WKT is a GIS format.  I think you are saying that being able to convert from it into ASCII art would assist you to better document your GIS code.  To me that would make it on-topic.

Comment: http://web.uta4you.at/shop/td/ might form part of the rendering process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this isn't perfect, but it's better than anything I've seen so far. Here's a command-line process that uses three commands:

1. The [`wellknown`](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown) command reads WKT from `stdin` and write GeoJSON.
2. The [`geotype`](https://github.com/morganherlocker/geotype) command reads GeoJSON from `stdin` and outputs a map, using color ANSI escape sequences.
3. Good old-fashioned `sed` [strips out these sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/240017).

The three commands can be piped together like this:

```
echo 'POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))' | \
  wellknown | \
  geotype -z 12 | \
  sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

Which outputs the following:

```
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::  
  ::::::::::::::::::::::    
  ::::::::::::::::::::      
  ::::::::::::::::::        
  ::::::::::::::::          
  ::::::::::::::            
  ::::::::::::::            
  ::::::::::::              
  ::::::::::                
  ::::::::                  
  ::::::                    
  ::::                      
  ::
```